# How to find the ARN of existing AWS lambda layer

Tags: terraform

I created a lambda layer using this script.

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_common_layer" {
  layer_name = "lambda_common_layer"
  s3_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.bucket}"
  s3_key = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.key}"
  s3_object_version = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.object_lambda_common_layer.version_id}"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.layer_zip_lambda_common_layer.output_base64sha256}"
  description = "Common layer providing logging"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.6"]
}
```

I also has a lambda definition which I want to use the layer in. To do that I need to pass a list of ARNs and I don't know how to get the ARN of existing lambda layer Those are different projects with separate Terraform scripts.
How to do that ?
Here is my lambda declaration

I tried to put only layer name as a resouce but it's getting highlighted

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_common_layer" {
layer_name = "lambda_common_layer"
}

...
  layers = ["${aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_common_layer.layer_arn}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to data source in the [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) from the project where the lambda layer resource was declared.

This is easiest way, in my mind, to do this is to use a remote state [backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html) to store the terraform state of each project so that you can reference it from other projects. In my experience the easiest remote state to set up is the [S3 remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html).

With that done, you can then include an `outputs.tf` file in your lambda layer project with something like:

```
output "lambda_layer_arn" {
   value = "${aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_common_layer.arn}"
}
output "lambda_layer_version_arn" {
   value = "${aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_common_layer.layer_arn}"
}
```

By outputting those values, they will be available in the remote state for other terraform modules to use.